# Java process use more memory than VisualVM shows

Tags: java, memory, ffmpeg, ram, visualvm

my java application works ~1 day,
(I use different libs for processing photo like ffmpeg, javacv, javacpp)
and then I see that my app use 9,5Gb RAM.

[system monitoring tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4AKc.png)

I don't understand why my app use so a lot of memory.

I set -Xmx6G

In VisualVM I see that heap space size 188M

[heap space in visualVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho10w.png)

Meta Space use 141M

[metaspace in visualVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wut0.png)

May be this helps

[allocated bytes in visualVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s4N9.png)

I read articles that Java use more RAM than heap space because there are JIT, Heap space, meta space, code, ant etc. But 9.5Gb is a lot of on my mind

Edited:

- Yes my app some times have exceptions java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Try playing with garbage collection in visualvm to see how much can be released.  If slowly growing over time use the profiler in visualvm to investigate.

Comment: Please make sure that you're using the latest version, JavaCV 1.5.5.

Comment: Yes, I using all latest version of libs

Comment: Make sure that you're calling `close()` on any objects that has such a method. If anything isn't getting deallocated quickly enough, that can result in large enough delays on Windows to cause OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 2):

I partly solve this problem, partly thanks Samuel Audet comment.
(But whatever heap spase use stable 125M, metaspace 100M but java process use 1,4Gb )

So problem was in code where I get frames from video.

My old code:

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber g = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file);
Java2DFrameConverter bimConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

g.start();

Frame grab = g.grab();
BufferedImage imageFrame = bimConverter.convert(grab);

g.stop();
```

And I couldn't even think until I checked all potentially classes that FFmpegFrameGrabber, Java2DFrameConverter, Frame is Autoclosable  and we need for each call close() when instance.

And in some part of code not close InputStream

Good code:

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber g = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file);
Java2DFrameConverter bimConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

g.start();

Frame grab = g.grab();
BufferedImage imageFrame = bimConverter.convert(grab);

g.stop();

g.close();
bimConverter.close();
grab.close();
```

Comment: BTW, we should use the try-with-resources statement instead of calling close() manually: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @SamuelAudet yes I use where it possible